# Custom styling cell in react-table Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, cell, react-table

I have a issue with display value with custom style to Cell in react-table of MUI. (Align center text in cell)

This is code to render cell to table

```
<TableBody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
  {rows?.map((row) => {
    prepareRow(row)
    const { key, ...getRowProps } = row.getRowProps()
    return (
      <Row
        onClick={() => hasRowClick && onRowClick(row)}
        hasRowClick={hasRowClick}
        hover
        key={key}
        {...getRowProps}
      >
        {row.cells.map((cell) => {
          const { key, ...getCellProps } = cell.getCellProps()

          return (
            <Cell variant="body" key={key} {...getCellProps}>
              {cell.render('Cell')}
            </Cell>
          )
        })}
      </Row>
    )
  })}

  {!loading && !data.length && (
    <Row>
      <Cell colSpan={headerGroups[headerGroups.length - 1]?.headers.length}>
        <EmptyTable />
      </Cell>
    </Row>
  )}
</TableBody>
```

Below is code create column for this table:

```
export const EmployeeTimeOffFields = {
  listFields: [
    {
      Header: i18n.t('employee.date'),
      accessor: 'date',
      display: true
    },
    {
      Header: i18n.t('employee.number_of_minutes'),
      accessor: 'number_of_minutes',
      Cell: ({ value }: CellProps<TimeOff>) => {
        return minutesToDays(value, 'string')
      },
      display: true
    }
  ],
  searchFields: [
    {
      Header: i18n.t('employee.date'),
      accessor: 'date',
      type: 'text',
      grid: { xs: 12, sm: 6, md: 6 },
      display: true
    }
  ],
  quickSearchField: {
    Header: i18n.t('employee.date'),
    accessor: 'date',
    type: 'text',
    grid: { xs: 12, sm: 6, md: 6 },
    display: true
  }
}
```

And i found a block of code in codesanbox.io that describe exactly what i expected. But it written by javascript (my teams use typescript).

```
function MyCell({ value, columnProps: { rest: { someFunc } } }) {
  return <p style={{color:'red', textAlign:'center'}}>{value}</p>
}
.
.
.
{
  Header: 'Profile Progress',
  accessor: 'progress',
  Cell: MyCell,
  getProps: () => ({ someFunc: () => alert("clicked")})
}
```

And only allow edit in listField, not allow edit inside return <TableBody.../> method.

(only write in this block):

```
  listFields: [
    {
      Header: i18n.t('employee.date'),
      accessor: 'date',
      display: true
    },
    {
      Header: i18n.t('employee.number_of_minutes'),
      accessor: 'number_of_minutes',
      Cell: ({ value }: CellProps<TimeOff>) => {
        return minutesToDays(value, 'string')
      },
      display: true
    }
  ],
```

Hope your help, thanks so much